How to properly apply metal grinding using MoveIt?
I am coming from mobile robotics background and recently started playing around with MoveIt for robotic arm manipulation.
Overall, it seems great that MoveIt already handles object recognition, inverse kinematic planning (path planning), obstacle detection and etc.
So if I want to perform a metal grinding and suppose I know the coordinates of the area in cartesian format, how to properly perform this using Moveit? My initial thought is to just move the arm as close as possible to the grinding area until it touches it (using torque sensors or something similar) and just turn on the grinder and push arm a bit more (4mm say), then move back the arm and using the camera (pointcloud match) detect if grinding is done or needs more grinding.
However this is only my novice way of thinking and I wonder if there are more experienced people who could tell me the better/proven ways to perform metal grinding?
